# cannot execute store procedure in phpmyadmin

Tags: stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

```
    Error in processing request: No routine with name `selectCategory` found 
    in database `xxx`.
```

This is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectCategory`()
BEGIN

SELECT category_id, name AS display_name

FROM category

ORDER BY name;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to run the stored procedure on the phpmyadmin site to check if the other problem I am having is due to php I wrote or the procedure itself, because of that error I cannot check and I do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: That's not enough SQL to define a stored procedure; it's just the innards.  Can you please include the full definition?

Comment: @DanFarrell done

Comment: When you define the procedure, do you set the database to xxx?

Comment: @Dan Farrell I am executin SQL syntax inside the xxx database. Afterwards you can see the procedure inside the database.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you are connecting to an instance which does not have the SP? check the db instance contains your SP.

Comment: I don't think thats possible, since I am trying to execute the procedure in the place where I created it, if that makes sense.